# Since water is not fluoridated in some countries, is it recommended that people swallow their toothpaste?

Tags: toothpaste, fluoride

In some countries, the water is not fluoridated. Since food contains very low amounts of fluoride, it may be beneficial to obtain some extra fluoride in some way. My question: is it recommended by health authorities that all adults who do not get their recommended dose of fluoride from drinking water swallow their toothpaste?

In one portion of toothpaste, there is [approximately](https://ods.od.nih.gov/factsheets/Fluoride-HealthProfessional/.) 1.3 mg of fluoride. So if people ingest all toothpaste after brushing and do this twice a day, this will add 2.6 mg of fluoride per day. This would help to get to the [recommended](https://ods.od.nih.gov/factsheets/Fluoride-Consumer/) 3 or 4 mg of fluoride per day.

However, toothpaste also contains other ingredients. Would it be harmful in some way to always swallow all toothpaste?

To emphasize that this question is different from other questions: I do not ask whether fluoride is harmful; rather, the question is whether the other ingredients of toothpaste can be harmful.

Comment: I don't understand what's wrong with the hyperlink?

Comment: Virtually all water contains naturally occurring fluoride. Do you have any idea how much is in yours? I would recommend you find out before making a practice of swallowing toothpaste.

Comment: @Carey Gregory, there is only 0.05 to 0.25 mg fluoride in a liter of drinking water here. So that will not help much to reach the recommended 3 mg.

Comment: In your edit you say the question is whether other ingredients in toothpaste are harmful, but you'd never guess that's the question from the title, which asks an entirely different question, and most of the body of the question which talks only about fluoride. To reframe the question as you wish, you need to completely rewrite it. I would suggest just asking a new question.